# How to edit form with hasMany (multiple rows)

Tags: forms, cakephp-2.0, has-many

I have a Unit which hasMany Images, and I'm trying to display an edit form for these images on my edit page.  My resulting html form input shows the wrong model, so the correct value for this data doesn't get populated.  Here is my view code:

```
<?php


echo $this->Form->create('Unit', array(
    'action' => 'edit',
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
        )
    )
);
echo $this->Form->hidden('id');

foreach($this->data['Image'] as $img) {

echo $this->Form->hidden('Image'.$img['id'].'id');

}
echo $this->Form->end('Update Photo');?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

My html ends up like this:

```
<form action="/units/edit/3" id="UnitEditForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][id]" value="3" id="UnitId"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][Image1id]" id="UnitImage1id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][Image2id]" id="UnitImage2id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][Image3id]" id="UnitImage3id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][Image4id]" id="UnitImage4id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][Image5id]" id="UnitImage5id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][Image6id]" id="UnitImage6id"/>
   <div class="submit">
       <input  type="submit" value="Update Photo"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

I have seen a number of tutorials, including the CakePHP manual which shows how you can enter 'Modelname.[0].field', etc, which is all fine and good for when you know how many rows you have, but when does that ever happen in a CMS?  I cannot seem to find any information on how to build this form by looping through all the records in the array of Images available.
Eventually, I want to  be able to have the hidden id field so the record can be updated, show the actual image (and the ability to change it), it's alt description (and the ability to change it), and I suppose another hidden field for the unit_id that associates it with this form.

**UPDATE**
using

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Image.'.$img['id'].'.id');
```

works now, but is returning this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][1][id]" value="2" id="Image1Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][2][id]" value="3" id="Image2Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][3][id]" value="4" id="Image3Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][4][id]" value="5" id="Image4Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][5][id]" value="6" id="Image5Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][6][id]" id="Image6Id"/>
```

I need to start from [0], not [1].  Instead of getting the number by 'id', I need to be getting the counted numbers in the $img array, correct?  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.  Take a look at the code below.  The key is starting a counter that loops through each item in the array, and using the output of the counter to generate the correct number of inputs.

```
$count=0;
foreach($this->data['Image'] as $img) {
echo $this->Form->hidden('Image.'.$count.'.id');
$count++;
}
```

this outputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[Unit][id]" value="3" id="UnitId"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][0][id]" value="1" id="Image0Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][1][id]" value="2" id="Image1Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][2][id]" value="3" id="Image2Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][3][id]" value="4" id="Image3Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][4][id]" value="5" id="Image4Id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][5][id]" value="6" id="Image5Id"/>
```

You can see that the correct value is populated.

Comment: Hey there, I had the same idea (with the count) and the input has the right value and everything. But I can´t get to save the data. Can you show the part of your controller? I am using contain getting the article and associated for the patchEntity.

Answer (score 4):

This line here is most likely causing your trouble:

```
    echo $this->Form->hidden('Image'.$img['id'].'id');
```

This builds the model.field as "Image1id" rather than what Cake expects "Image.1.id". Try rewriting it like this:

```
    echo $this->Form->hidden('Image.'.$img['id'].'.id');
```

Comment: This works!  Unfortunately, $img[] is returning values STARTING with [1] instead of [0], so by the time my loop gets to the last Image.id, it is not displaying a value(cause that record doesn't exist in the array).  Updating the OP for reference.